# Find relations between angles.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have an equation where $\cos(x)=k\cdot\cos(y)$ where $x$, $y$ angles and $k$ a real number. I wonder if I can find another expression from the above equation with $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(y)$.

I will clarify what i want to do. I know that $\cos(x)=k\cdot\cos(y)$ and I want to solve another equation where both $\cos(x)$, $\sin(x)$ and also $\cos(y)$ and $\sin(y)$ are present. I only know that there is a relation between $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(y)$. So may be I must find the relation between x and y as angles. Am I right?

Comment: What about using sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2 = 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

We can get
$$\cos^2x=k^2\cos^2y$$$$\Rightarrow 1-\sin^2x=k^2(1-\sin^2y)$$$$\Rightarrow\sin^2x=k^2\sin^2y+1-k^2.$$

Here, I used the following relation :

$$\cos^2\alpha=1-\sin^2\alpha.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(x)=\sin(90-x)$

so:

$\sin(90-x)=k\cdot\sin(90-y)$